# Certain Lie algebra structure on $\chi^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ or $\chi^{\infty}(S^{2})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras

Is there a lie  algebra structure $ [ \;.  ] $ on $\chi^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ or $\chi^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^{2})$ which is not isomorphic to the standard structures but satisfies the following:

> For every two vector fields $X,Y$  with $[X,Y]=0$, every limit cycle of $X$ must be invariant under $Y$.

The motivation is the following:

The usual Lie algebra structures satisfies the above dynamical property, but unfortunately a generic vector field has trivial centralizer in the standard Lie algebra structures. So we hope that for this (possible) new structure the centralizers are rich.(Are not trivial).

Note that a limit cycle for  a  vector  field is  an isolated closed orbit.

Comment: this probably needs some work to get it into shape, but is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_Lie_algebra on the right track?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Thank you very much for introducing me this concept. In that link I did not find examples of quasi frobenius Lie algebra. Does the Lie algebra of vector fields satisfiy this property?  How we apply this concept to the main question.